# Adding methods to a list in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala and I want to add a function to a list. I have the following:

```
  var l2: List[() => Unit] = List()
  def foo() {
    println("In foo")
  }
```

And now I want to add a method to the list.

```
() => println("x") :: l2
```

It compiles but it doesn't work at runtime.

Next question: Why doesn't the following compile?

```
l2 = foo :: l2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does `l2 = (foo) :: l2` compile?

Comment: You might want to add, why your code does not work at runtime and what the compiler error message is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `() => println("x") :: l2` is interpreted as `() => (println("x") :: l2)`. That is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `List[Any]` (after type inference).

As @dursun states, you want to write:

```
(() => println("x")) :: l2
```

Further, `l2 = foo :: l2` does not compile because Scala wants you to state explicitly, if you use a function value rather than apply it (basically to protect the programmer from misuse). Use:

```
foo _ :: l2
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a correct syntax

```
() => println("x") :: l2
```

the correct one is

```
(() => println("x")) :: l2
```

and why `l2 = foo :: l2` does not compile is because the type of `foo` does not compliant with  l2 to understand it deeply try following

```
foo.toString
```

however followings will be compiled

```
var fn = {() => println("y")}
l2 = fn :: l2
```

or

```
foo _ :: l2
```

Comment: `() => println("x") :: l2` is correct syntax, but interpreted as `() => (println("x") :: l2)`

Comment: yes you are right I just wanted to say it does not work the way that @NMO wanted.

Comment: Sorry, nitpicking again. `foo.toString` does not return the type of (or information about) `foo`, but calls `foo` and returns the result (The unit-value `()` in this case).